# Apply a CSS class to a selector (in CSS)

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a CSS class:

```
.text-red {
  color: red;
}
```

This class is defined elsewhere, may be supercomplex, and is not editable.

In my DOM I have several paragraphs. I want to apply text-red class to all paragraphs. Of course I may write that directly:

```
<p class="text-red">XXX</p>
<p class="text-red">YYY</p>
<p class="text-red">ZZZ</p>
<p class="text-red">WWW</p>
```

but it is so redundant. I'd like to write in my CSS file something like:

```
p {
  .text-red
}
```

so that all "p" elements have that class applied.
Clearly this is not a CSS valid rule. How may I do?

Comment: You can do this with one line of js or jquery, would you like to see that solution? or are you going for purely css?

Comment: Yes, purely css

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do so with SASS pre-processor by using `@extend`.

https://sass-lang.com/guide

Ohterwise, you could use JavaScript (jQuery) as well:

```
$('p').addClass('.text-red')
```

But maybe the easiest would be to copy the properties to the `p` selector?

Comment: How would you do in SASS? I tried with:

    p {
        @extend .text-red
    }

But I get: The selector ".text-red" was not found. Clearly the class do exists, but it comes from a standard css file, so I guess SASS is not seeing it...

Comment: You're on a good way! I would change the original file to '.scss' and then import it by using @import

Answer (score -1):

This is valid CSS:

```
p.text-red { color: red; }
```

Comment: that forces to add the class to all the needed html tags contrary to his question

Comment: Not contrary at all - the OP states "I want to apply text-red class to all paragraphs:" and again "all "p" elements"

Comment: correct my fault

Comment: Thanks - pls remove your downvote ;-)

Comment: was not me I assure you, but will up-vote

Comment: The OP appears to want to apply the styles for `.text-red` to all `<p>` tags, without adding the class to each `<p>` tag. This code requires that the class be added to each `<p>` tag.

Comment: Nope - I've read the question again and do not agree. They've even proposed `p { .text-red }` which is essentially close to my answer.

Comment: Fair enough. In my opinion, `p { .text-red }` is an attempt to apply `.text-red` styles to all `<p>` elements, without explicitly defining those styles for `<p>` elements. It seems the OP wants to avoid adding the class to every `<p>` element because it is "redundant". I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: I agree with @showdev. Maybe it's the wording, but a solution would simply be `p { color: red }` or whatever styles are in `.text-red`. It may be redundant from a CSS standpoint (as you're not including the original class), but you don't have to add the class to the markup.

Answer (score -2):

Referring you to Child combinator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

example

```
.text-red > p {
  ...
}
```

this selects all the p children of .text-red class

Comment: So you mean to place the class on the container? Not seems really related to the question, but in some situations it can be useful.

Comment: Some down-votes need to be explained, at least to learn something

Comment: @Qwertiy he mentioned that he doesn't want to specify on each html element. that's the reason for the approach

Comment: The OP does not seem to be targeting `<p>` elements as children of `.text-red`.

Comment: @AlexMounir, he asks about smth like `@include` or `@extends` from css preprocessors. You don't answer that question. I haven't voted on your answer, but I think downvotes are related to that fact.

Comment: The op also doesn't want to apply a class to every p tag so the proposed solution could be argued as valid

Comment: I see no mention of @include or extends

Comment: I see. So your intent is that the OP wrap all the `<p>` elements in a parent element with the `.text-red` class? That's a viable option. I suggest including a working example, to help demonstrate.

Comment: correct, I believe it fits the required criteria and explains basic/core css selectors.